# Is there a way to run a Def Query on an AOI?

Tags: arcgis-10.1

I want to spatially only display features within an AOI boundary.  Is there a way to do this like with the def query tab in a feature classes attributes?

Comment: That only selects what's inside the AOI.  It still displays outside.  I want it to dynamically cut off everything outside of it.

Comment: For a map (data frame) or layer? i.e. do you want the entire map to be cut down to a local area or do you want other data to cover the page and just have a small section of a layer trimmed to the AOI.

Comment: Try using `Create Layer From Selected Features`.  I will post a more complete answer when SE lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Clip Options in the Data Frame Properties -> Data Frame tab - and Clip certain layers to your AOI for display only.  See attached image

[image]

Comment: That's what I was getting at, however this does ALL layers. If the op wants to reduce only 1 layer of many this won't help. There is an interface that will do only one layer but that doesn't get saved with the document and can only be accessed in ArcObjects.

Comment: So the exclude layers options don't get saved with the MXD?  Strange!

Comment: The clip to shape option gets saved with the MXD as it's a ArcMap setting, the one to which I refer is an ArcObject interface IClipFiler which does not get saved with the MXD.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think the person was using ArcObjects - the ArcMap interface I think will work for their needs!

Comment: Not mentioned but a possibility. Another option is cartographic representation, once converted the unwanted sections can be suppressed.

Comment: Spatial definition queries I have only seen in SDE: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/enhanci-205816615.htm using the funtion *sde.overlaps* like this sde.st_overlaps (b.shape, sde.st_buffer (w.shape, 50)) = 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is create a layer based on a selection.

1. Select the features in your AOI, either graphically or with the `Select by Location` tool.
2. Right-click in the table of contents on the layer with the selected features.
3. Choose `Selection` and then `Create Layer with Selected Features`.
4. Turn off the original layer to see just the features in the AOI.

Note that this new layer will not display features added to the original layer after the new layer was created, but it should reflect other edits to the original layer.